# Deleting images from parse from table View

Tags: swift, uitableview, parse-platform

I am using parse for my project.  I am returning true for `canEditRowAtIndexPath`　. I was looking at documents and sample projects and I don't see a place where it tells how to delete.  I am using the code below to delete  from parse. However　 I am getting an error at imageFiles? . It says use of undefined identifier.

```
     func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {
        let objectToDelete = imageFiles?[indexPath.row] as! PFFile
        objectToDelete.deleteInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if (success) {
                self.loadObjects()
            } else {
            }
        }
    } else if editingStyle == .Insert {
    }
}
```

I am converting images to NSData then PFFile. I am using the below code to retrieve images.

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let singleCell:SingleRowCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("mySingleCell")as! SingleRowCell
        singleCell.topsLabel.text = imageText [indexPath.row]
        imageFiles[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock{
          (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if imageData != nil {
            let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
            singleCell.topsImageView.image = image
        }else {
            println(error)
            }}


        return singleCell
        }}

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool{
        return true
    }
```

Is my method of deleting files wrong or mistake in coding.
Thank you.

Comment: Is imageFiles a global variable?

Comment: Hello, imageFIles is in the same file so shouldn't make a difference even if its a global variable.  I could also show you other piece of code if you have any ideas of other mistake.

Comment: ok I got it. I am saving images using PFFile. PFFile does not let users delete it from the first place. There is another type called PFObjects but I am not sure if it could handle images.